# LIstado de cliente en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo una base de datos paralela a la de wordpress en la cual le muestra al cliente una lista de sus clientes. Hata aca todo perfectos. Como trabajo en wordpress, he creado una pagina que se llama "Listado de Clientes", el probema es que cuando hago el listado me lo muestra en todas las paginas. Como hago para ver el listado en una sola página?

```
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");

while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
 echo 'Cliente '.$row['empresas'];
}
?>
```

Comment: El problema es que seguramente estás poniendo ese código en la plantilla, y por eso se muestra en todas partes. En los casos de querer mostrar contenido en alguna parte específica, lo mejor es hacerlo a través de los llamados *hooks*. Se trata de algo parecido a un identificador en una página o post o en un grupo de ellos el cual ejecuta un código en particular (por ejemplo el código que muestras en tu pregunta). Así, el contenido se muestra sólo donde esté el *hook*. [Aquí se explica con detalle](https://platzi.com/blog/hooks-wordpress/) qué son los *hooks*. Además, está en castellano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estás colocando el código en la plantilla del template donde muestra la página. Posiblemente llamado "page.php".

Una vez tienes colocado, debes hacer un condicional. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php 
if (is_page("nombre-de-tu-página")) {
// Aquí se mostrará la información si está dentro de esta página
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
     while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
           echo 'Cliente '.$row['empresas'];
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Gracias Jok... hice la prueba y funcionó. Perdón la tardanza...